# Images in nested <defs> do not show up in chromium

Tags: svg, chromium

I have some SVG files whereby one includes the other by using `<use />` elements. To merge all those files into one resulting one, I have written some code that transforms `./main.svg` from below:

```
#file: ./svg/shared.svg
<svg>
  <image xlink:href="../img/bg.png" id="bg" />
</svg>

#file: ./svg/index.svg
<svg id="index">
  <use xlink:href="./shared.svg#bg" />
</svg>

#file: ./main.svg
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="./svg/index.svg#index" />
</svg>
```

into:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <svg id="svg-index">
      <defs>
        <image xlink:href="./img/bg.png" id="img-bg" />
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#img-bg" />
    </svg>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#svg-index" />
</svg>
```

So basically all urls and Ids are resolved and referenced nodes are imported. The script works fine, in Firefox and the result works as well in Inkscape. **BUT** in chromium the images do not show up. They are loaded, what I can see from the networking tab.

If I modify the images' `xlink:href` (inspector panel) by adding a little `#qwertz` at the end of **one image**, all of them show up, so that seams to be browser related, since the result works in FF and Inkscape.

Any Idea how to fix that?

**UPDATE**

One thing that may have some effect here is whether the manipulated SVG is already inserted into the dom or not. So this code makes the images appear:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('image')].forEach(
      img => img.setAttribute('xlink:href',
                img.getAttribute('xlink:href')
    )
  );

}, 0)
```

But that feels really hackish and I am really interested in a »cleaner« solution here…

Comment: Is your script executed in the browser and trying to show the resulting document immediately, or is the result written to file and only then opened in a browser?

Comment: It is executed in the browser and tries to show it immidiatly

Comment: In this case, please show the script. Do you make sure that all de-serializing operations correctly detect the SVG namespace?

Comment: good question. Script is lengthy, but queries are done via xpath and `//svg:use[@xlink:href]` is used to get the usual suspects and `document.importNode(<node>, true)` to import those... So, kind of yes, i am kind of sure to have dealt right with the namespaces...